# Accessing list in pandas dataframe from within DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a database that contains the column 'tchname' with each entry containing a string such as 'John Smith' or 'Mr John Adam Smith', where the first or second word (depending on if there's an honorific) of each string is the first name and the final word is the surname.

What I wish to do is create two new columns, 'firstname' and 'surname'. Getting the surname is easy enough, however my approach to getting the first name, while it works, feels very hacky:

```
import pandas as pd

# Typical data example:
data = {'tchname': ['MISS NANDA DEVI', 'RAJIK HUSSAIN-III',
                    'MAJJI VENKATA KANAKA DURGA RANI']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Split words in teacher names into list.
df['tchname'] = df['tchname'].str.split()

# Extract first word from tchname lists.
df['firstname'] = df['tchname'].str[0].str.title()

# If firstname matches item in honorific, replace with second tchname entry
df['placeholder'] = df['tchname'].str[1].str.title()
honorific = ['Dr', 'Miss', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms']
df.loc[df['firstname'].isin(honorific), 'firstname'] \
    = df.loc[df['firstname'].isin(honorific), 'placeholder']
df = df.drop(columns='placeholder')

# Extract last name from tchname lists.
df['surname'] = df['tchname'].str[-1].str.title()
```

Right now, this correctly identifies the names as 'Nanda Devi', 'Rajik Hussain-Iii', and 'Majji Rani'. Doing this via use of 'placeholder' seems like a hacky approach to me; it only takes a few seconds to complete (over a database of several million entries), however as it's unnecessarily writing invalid first names (such as 'Miss') to the database, and then overwriting them, I'd like to know if there's a better approach I can take so I'm only iterating over and writing to the database once per entry?

Comment: If you had to reduce the length of your post by 90%, and still convey you message, how would you explain what you want to do? Feel free to post a mock `dataframe`.

Comment: I agree with @NicolasGervais, some example data is basically a must-have. Names are a messy, messy thing. Are all the names guaranteed to have only two parts? No dashes? What about accents?

Comment: Thanks for responding; sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I've added a mock dataframe to the code and removed the handling of fringe cases to make the question shorter (I've also reworded the question slightly). What I'd like to do is find a better approach (if possible) to getting the first and last names from the data frame as I'm not convinced my approach (whilst it works) is particularly good, having to iterate over and write to the database multiple times instead of handling honorifics on the first pass.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm accounting for dashes, although for my purpose (and given the large data set and how unlikely accents are here), dropping a few valid entries is acceptable (although I want to try to avoid as many invalid entries getting through as possible). As per Nicolas' suggestion, however, I've now removed the handling of fringe cases in the example code to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: @TobyHawkins If you’ve got a complete list of honourifics, I’m thinking regex. I can give it a shot in a few minutes.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks. Honorifics can be assumed to be only those given and I can always add to this list if needed. I did consider regex, however I avoided it due to its inherent performance issues. I'll add my attempt at this as an answer anyway (since it is a neat solution and won't fit in this comment), but leave this question open for a few days and if you or anyone else has a better solution that would be great!

Comment: @TobyHawkins Do you have any test data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204242/discussion-between-toby-hawkins-and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (relatively?) simple regex solution. In this case, it should be used with [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract). It will accept any none-whitespace character as part of a name, it can, and should be specialized further.

```
^(?:(?:Dr|Miss|Mr|Mrs|Ms)\s+)?(\S+)(?:.*)\s+(\S+)$
```

Don't forget the flags!

```py
re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE
```

I will look into creating the regex programatically, as things might get annoying if the number of honourifics/titles increases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander Cécile for his suggestion on using regex. I tried to avoid this due to the poor performance of regex, however here's a solution based on it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Typical data example:
data = {'tchname': ['MISS NANDA DEVI', 'RAJIK HUSSAIN-III',
                    'MAJJI VENKATA KANAKA DURGA RANI']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set firstname to first or second word of tchname based on honorific presence.
df['firstname'] = np.where(df['tchname'].str.match(
    '^(Dr|Miss|Mr|Mrs|Ms) ', case=False),
    df['tchname'].str.split().str[1].str.capitalize(),
    df['tchname'].str.split().str[0].str.capitalize())

df['surname'] = df['tchname'].str.split().str[-1].str.capitalize()
```

I'd say the code is definitely clearer, and from the view of maintainability is probably a decent solution, however as expected, this runs slower than the original (execution time of ~6.3 seconds vs ~5.4 seconds for the code in the question on my machine using a large data set), so I won't accept this answer unless there are no better alternatives suggested.